# Backbone.js Select Change Event In Firefox

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For some reason this only happens in Firefox:

```
"change #CardSelector": "selectCard"
```

This event on the Backbone view will not call selectCard when the select box changes.

But if I use this:

```
this.$("#CardSelector").change(this.selectCard)
```

It all seems fine. Is there something I'm missing? Its working in Chrome.

Thanks,

Comment: does is work with `this.$el.on('change', '#CardSelector', this.selectCard)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be something else going on in some code you did not post.

Here is a jsFiddle that I tried in FF on Windows: http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/VE5wm/

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    events: {
        "change #CardSelector": "selectCard" 
    },

    selectCard:function(e){
        this.$el.append('<div>' + this.$('#CardSelector').val() + '</div>');
    }
});
```

Is there something you see here that might be different from what you have tried?

Comment: Any reason to use `this.$('#CardSelector')` vs. `$(e.target)`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys. It looks like it was a browser bug in that Mac Firefox build. A Quick update fixed the issue and the event now fires.

Thanks.